# Moving duplicate directory structures onto one another

Tags: svn, merge

I have duplicate directory structures in two locations that I need to merge together in an svn repository. By "merge" I mean I want all files and folder that are unique to structure `b` to be moved into structure `a`. When I try to do this using `svn move` I get the error

```
svn: Path 'com' already exists
```

The folders look like:

```
src
 -> com
    -> (many more files and directories)
 -> java
    -> com
       -> (some files and folders, some folders overlap but all files are unique)
```

`src\com` is `a` and `src\java\com` is `b`.

Comment: After talking to several people and experimenting for a couple hours I am wondering if this is possible with svn. My experience with svn over the last week has hugely dropped my opinion of it. Go with Mercurial or git imo. Unfortunately not an option in my case, it's a 10 year old repository with 50 devs working with it and 50+ other people reading from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to several people I have come to the conclusion that svn does not support this behavior.

It is possible to produce the same results by writing a script that reads the contents of java\com and produces a svn move command for each item.  If there are overlapping files and directories on many levels then this would not work however. Directory overlaps could be handled by expanding the script to crawl the directory hierarchy, tagging the overlaps and moving their contents as above. File overlaps would have to be handled manually and no script will be able to decide which file to keep in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could svn merge the entire history of the source 'com' path in to the destination path,  which will preserve the history of those files e.g.

```
svn merge -r 1:HEAD svn://repository-path-to/com working-copy-path-to/com
```

You need to make sure the revision range includes the revision that adds the first files to the source 'com' folder.

Comment: This did not work. I ran every variation of this I could and nothing happened, no errors, no changes, nothing. I appreciate the effort though :)